# Hangfire running older version of my code intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, hangfire

I've been recently facing a strange issue with Hangfire and an ASP.Net app hosted on a single server (Virtual VM).

My code runs fine on the local machine, however, once the code is uploaded to the server it seems that I am getting the results of some older code that still exists somewhere.

Here is what the background job is supposed to do:

1. Query the database multiple times (some heavy queries are involved)
2. Write the results to an excel file
3. Send the file in an email.

What happens is that for the same request I am randomly getting 3 different outcomes. Either an empty excel file in the email with only the header data filled, an excel file that is partially filled, or a complete excel file.

I've disabled sending the email to debug but between one request and the other I am still getting emails (!)

I've restarted the IIS server, restarted the web app, deleted the directory of the web app and redeployed to no avail.

Hangfire is great but I am afraid that I have no choice but to look for an alternative if I do not overcome this problem (it's been a couple days of debugging). Is there a way to properly restart Hangfire?

Here is my setup for reference:

```
Global.asax.xs
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSerilogLogProvider()
                .UseSqlServerStorage("Server=localhost; Database = hangfire; Integrated Security = SSPI;", new SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true
                });

            var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                WorkerCount = 1
            };
            yield return new BackgroundJobServer(options);
```

and this is how the job is called:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => (new cReport()).GetReportInBackground(itemsToReport, tbStartDate.Text, tbEndDate.Text, ME));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hangfire saves his configs in own scheme in database. You can check there for more information

Comment: @KamranMammadov true, and I can see that there are 3 servers running in the Server table. I triggered these jobs and each time the job is picked by one of 3 servers, and I am getting a different excel file depending on the server that processed the job. How do I safely shutdown the other ones?

Comment: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/457 maybe help

Comment: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20210226-MultipleHangfireInstancesInOneDatabase.html